# Running private method out of an other method

Tags: javascript, cordova

I initialize with the following Code the Class `ReadConfig`:

`var myReadConfig = new ReadConfig();`

This works fine and the `alert("2")` appears.

After that I run the statement `window.requestFileSystem(...)` which calls the Method `gotFSReader`. 
But I never see the `alert("3");` result.

How should I run this Method `gotFSReader` out of  `window.requestFileSystem(...)` ? If I run it outside of a class it works completely...

My Class:

```
  var ReadConfig = function(){
        var path = "Zugangsdaten.txt";
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFSReader, failReader);
        alert("2");

        var gotFSReader = function(fileSystem) {
            alert("3");
            fileSystem.root.getFile(path, null, gotFileEntryReader, failReader);

        }

        var gotFileEntryReader = function(fileEntry) {
            fileEntry.file(gotFileReader, failReader);
            alert("4");
        }

        var gotFileReader = function(file){
            readAsText(file);
        }

        var readAsText = function(file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
                console.log("Read as text");
                handleLocalPasswort(evt.target.result);
            };
            reader.readAsText(file);
        }

        var failReader = function(evt) {
            console.log(evt.target.error.code);
        }

        var handleLocalPasswort = function(fileStr){
            if(fileStr=="" || fileStr == null){
                return;
            }

            var arrayItems = fileStr.split(";");
            document.getElementById('tb_benutzer').value = arrayItems[0];
            document.getElementById('tb_password').value = arrayItems[1];
            document.getElementById('tb_knr').value = arrayItems[2];
            checkLogin();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is structured incorrectly. You're not initializing that variable ("gotFSReader") until *after* you pass the value to that function. Therefore, you're passing `undefined`, and not a reference to the function.

Move the `window.requestFileSystem()` call to after that initialization, or declare your functions with function declaration statements:

```
    function gotFSReader(fileSystem) {
        alert("3");
        fileSystem.root.getFile(path, null, gotFileEntryReader, failReader);
    }
```

If you do that, then it'll work, because function declaration statements are always treated as if they occur at the beginning of the containing function.

Variable declarations are also hoisted, but there's a difference: only the actual declaration part of a `var` statement is treated as if it occurs at the start of the function. The initialization is done at the point in the function where the `var` actually appears.  Thus, in your code, the variable called "gotFSReader" is *declared* at the point you call `requestFileSystem()`, but it's not yet initialized.

Comment: And how to fix it? Should I write: function gotFSReader(fileSystem) {... ? Is it object-oriented?

Comment: The function will work properly if you use a function declaration statement. If you don't want to for some reason (it has nothing to do with being "object-oriented" in any case), you can just move that call to `requestFileSystem()` to the bottom of your main function.